# Design pattern for synchronizing shared domain models

Tags: design-patterns

Although I'm familiar with the design patterns described in The Gang of Four, on an enterprise level there will be a lot of patterns that I've never heard of. Hopefully there is one that will inspire a solution to the problem I'm facing at work:

I have three applications that are working together. Let's call  them ApplA, ApplB, and ApplC. They share some domain models, e.g. the class MyEntity

```
 public class MyEntity
 {
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //other properties 
 }
```

It is possible for the user to rename such an object using ApplA. When that happens, action should take place in **both** ApplB and ApplC. This is enabled by using queuing (Kafka, but the choice of queuing system probably doesn't matter). Following the happy path, both applications pick up the message from the queue, and perform their respective actions.

However, the alternative path is that either ApplB or ApplC fails when processing a message from the queue. Say application ApplB fails, then ApplC should not perform its action, or alternatively undo it's action. Is there any pattern / guidance on how to address such issues.

**Edit**: In the text above, I talked about renaming `MyEntity`, but I see how that statement could be misinterpreted. With renaming, I didn't intend to change the class name, rather that an object of type `MyEntity` is being renamed (note the property Name). So to give a better and more explicit example, consider multiple applications making use of a `Person` entity.

```
 public class Person
 {
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    //other properties 
 }
```

If a person changes last name (when women in the Netherlands get married, it's still common practice for them to take the last name of their husband), all relevant applications have to perform some business logic. Note that it's not just a matter of one database being updated, more business logic has to executed. Now what if one of the applications fail at doing its actions while the others succeed, what pattern / programming practice is tackling such a problem?

Comment: Design patterns are for code in the same app. Nothing is cross-app. You're description of how the three apps work resembles the **Chain of responsibility** pattern, but again that's only for code in the same app. Consider merging the three apps in one.

Comment: Two of the three apps are stand alone products that we don't directly develop ourselves, we have merely created addons. Merging the apps is thus not an option.

Comment: What addons? It seems to me that your app is calling the other two apps? If that's the case, then you can use the **Chain of responsibility** pattern in your app to control how you're calling the other two apps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention domain models as part of the methodology, I'm going to propose an answer of [patterns for context mapping in the context of DDD (domain-driven design)](https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-domain-driven). The domain models may or may not be similar for different *contexts* (applications). You can read more about each pattern on the link, but here they are:

- Shared Kernel
- Customer/Supplier Development Teams
- Conformist
- Anti-corruption Layer
- Separate Ways

If I'm not mistaken, Apache Kafka is a kind of "anti-corruption layer".

Domain patterns are out of the scope of the GoF (software class patterns), since the modeling is at a different level.

With regards to your "renaming" problem, it's hard to say when you don't give more details about what is the class being renamed and what are the other applications' assumptions about names. Renaming a domain class of "Student" to "Fish" in applications that are supposed to work in a university would not make any sense. It really depends on specifics many times.

Comment: @SimonAx If a person changed names, and an app failed to update itself, you'd need a fault tolerance pattern to handle this. Robert Hanmer has a book on them. Some patterns even involve human intervention, e.g., an operator can correct the rename on the failed app manually, or undo it from the other apps. There are automated solution as well.